# Understanding what is being asked: Assembly Program

Tags: assembly

I am new to writing assembly code and I am trying to figure this question out:
"Append to your program code and use RAM addressing to move the data from bank 3 to bank 0. Specifically move the data from R0 bank 3 to R0 bank 0, R1 bank 3 to R1 bank 0."

I am not entirely sure how I would go about doing this.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
;LN# [ADDR ] Source Code 
 1   [-----] $MOD51     ; This includes 8051 definitions for the  Metalink assembler
 2   [-----] 
 3   [00000] Mov R0, #00H ; LOAD 00H to Register R0
 4   [00002] Mov R1, #01H ; LOAD 01H to Register R1
 5   [00004] Mov R2, #02H ; LOAD 02H to Register R2
 6   [00006] Mov R3, #03H ; LOAD 03H to Register R3
 7   [00008] Mov R4, #04H ; LOAD 04H to Register R4
 8   [0000A] Mov R5, #05H ; LOAD 05H to Register R5
 9   [0000C] Mov R6, #06H ; LOAD 06H to Register R6
10  [0000E] Mov R7, #07H ; LOAD 07H to Register R7
11  [00010] nop
12  [-----] 
13  [-----] 
14  [-----] 
15  [00011] setb psw.3
16  [-----] 
17  [00013] Mov R0, #10H ; LOAD 10H to Register R0
18  [00015] Mov R1, #11H ; LOAD 11H to Register R1
19  [00017] Mov R2, #12H ; LOAD 12H to Register R2
20  [00019] Mov R3, #13H ; LOAD 13H to Reigster R3
21  [0001B] Mov R4, #14H ; LOAD 14H to Register R4
22  [0001D] Mov R5, #15H ; LOAD 15H to Register R5
23  [0001F] Mov R6, #16H ; LOAD 16H to Register R6
24  [00021] Mov R7, #17H ; LOAD 17H to Register R7
25  [00023] nop
26  [-----] 
27  [00024] setb psw.4
28  [-----] 
29  [00026] Mov R0, #20H ; LOAD 20H to Register R0
30  [00028] Mov R1, #21H ; LOAD 21H to Register R1
31  [0002A] Mov R2, #22H ; LOAD 22H to Register R2
32  [0002C] Mov R3, #23H ; LOAD 23H to Register R3
33  [0002E] Mov R4, #24H ; LOAD 24H to Register R4
34  [00030] Mov R5, #25H ; LOAD 25H to Register R5
35  [00032] Mov R6, #26H ; LOAD 26H to Register R6
36  [00034] Mov R7, #27H ; LOAD 27H to Register R7
37  [00036] nop 
38  [-----] 
39  [00037] setb psw.5
40  [-----] 
41  [00039] Mov R0, #30H ; LOAD 30H to Register R0
42  [0003B] Mov R1, #31H ; LOAD 31H to Register R1
43  [0003D] Mov R2, #32H ; LOAD 32H to Register R2
44  [0003F] Mov R3, #33H ; LOAD 33H to Register R3
45  [00041] Mov R4, #34H ; LOAD 34H to Register R4
46  [00043] Mov R5, #35H ; LOAD 35H to Register R5
47  [00045] Mov R6, #36H ; LOAD 36H to Register R6
48  [00047] Mov R7, #37H ; LOAD 37H to Register R7
```

49  [00049] nop

Comment: Comments that explain *what* the instruction does are usually useless.  Explain *why*, or leave it out to reduce clutter.  Always assume the person reading your code knows the instruction set and syntax, unless you're doing something clever or obscure (taking advantage of a rarely-used side effect of an instruction or something).  Your comments here are pure clutter.  I have no idea what architecture this is, but I sill didn't need those comments to tell me it was a move-immediate into a register.

Comment: I can see how the comments do cause unnecessary clutter. Adding comments in no matter what was something that I was recently taught to do.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely should always comment your asm.  However, you need to step back on level from what the instructions do to *why* you used that instruction, and what algorithm it's implementing.  Or just which high-level variable is currently live in that register.  Not every line needs its own comment.  Comments that add no information beyond what the source code literally says are useless in asm and any other language, unless you're teaching someone a new language.  Resist the temptation to comment that way when you're learning a new language yourself.

Comment: I understand, thank you for that tip! That will be very helpful with my future programs and projects.

Comment: Getting back to the question however, do you have any advice or help that you could give to help me solve / understand what the question is asking?

Comment: Nope, like I said, I don't even know what architecture this is for.  You didn't tag it anything other than "assembly", and it's not something I recognize.  I suspect that a loop will be helpful, but maybe not if you need to use lots of registers like that (you can't loop over registers on normal ISAs (not counting self-modifying code)).  I have no idea what "bank" even means in this context.  I'm used to flat memory, or x86 segments.